# Qual è il senso di "trionfo" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La Storia*, di Elsa Morante, ho letto:

> Mussolini e Hitler, a loro modo, erano due sognatori; ma qui si manifesta la loro diversità nativa. La visione onirica del «duce» italiano (rispondente a una sua voglia materiale di vita) era un festival da commedia, dove fra labari e **trionfi** lui, vassalluccio d’intrallazzo, recitava la parte di certi antichi vassalli beatificati (i cesari, gli augusti...) sopra una folla vivente umiliata al rango di fantoccio.

Non riesco a capire cosa sono questi "trionfi"  a cui allude questo passaggio. Ho cercato il termine "trionfo" in alcuni dizionari, ma non so vedere a quale accezione corrisponde l'uso che se ne fa nel testo. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Trovi un perfetto esempio nel ciclo dei [“trionfi di Cesare” di Mantegna](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trionfi_di_Cesare), in particolare la prima tela. Le processioni con insegne in stile romano erano comuni nel ventennio (ma anche nella Germania nazista, per la verità). Il ciclo di nove tele è conservato a Hampton Court (presso Londra), in una sala presso l'antica vigna; purtroppo, le condizioni delle tele impongono che siano solo debolmente illuminate. Visita raccomandata a tutto il complesso.

Comment: @egreg: Hai ragione! Le ricordo di quando ho letto *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credo che un indizio lo possa dare la parola associata a "trionfo", in questo caso "labaro", ed il seguito della frase, dove vengono menzionati "cesari" ed "augusti".

Nella Roma antica il "trionfo" era una cerimonia (la massima onorificenza a tutti gli effetti) aggiudicabile ad un generale in seguito ad una vittoria militare.

Il "labaro" invece era, se la memoria mi assiste, una insegna militare d'epoca imperiale.

In questo caso credo proprio che l'uso di questi due termini stia a indicare la pomposità e le reminiscenze imperiali che la visione del duce ispirava.

Answer (score 7):

Il significato che si addice al passaggio da te citato per [trionfo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trionfo/) è il seguente

> 1. Il massimo onore che, in Roma antica, veniva tributato su decreto del senato al comandante supremo che aveva riportato una grande
>    vittoria sul nemico, e che veniva celebrato solennemente **con un corteo**
>    che dal Campo Marzio giungeva fino al Campidoglio, dove il trionfatore
>    compiva l’offerta del lauro trionfale e il sacrificio rituale a Giove
>    Capitolino:

L’altro termine presente nel passaggio, [labaro](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/labaro/), infatti significa

> 2. Vessillo di forma simile allo stendardo di Costantino, adoperato nel medioevo come insegna dei cavalieri e dei comuni d’Italia, e in
>    tempi più recenti come insegna di associazioni combattentistiche,
>    ex-combattentistiche, politiche, religiose, ecc.

Mussolini, come del resto quasi tutti i dittatori di tutte le epoche, sentiva il bisogno di affermare il suo potere e dominio con cortei plateali in cui venivano esposti vessilli che richiamavano la gloria e la potenza dell’impero romano.

L’effetto però, come ricorda l’autrice, era tutt’altro che solenne e cadeva nel grottesco.